# Swift 5 dynamic dispatch not routing as expected

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, dynamic-dispatch

Swift does an incredible amount with type inference and dispatch optimization, but I've hit on a condition I've been trying to find a work around for. I'm not sure if this is current limitation of Swift or should be filed as a Radar (knowing compiler bugs are rare).

Sorry for the long code snippet, here's the cut down code for example (more after the issue) ...

```swift
/// Command executor for HTTP transports
class HttpExecutor: Executor {
    func execute<T: Command>(command: T) {
        print("Not a valid HttpCommand")
    }

    func execute<T: HttpCommand>(command: T) {
        print("HttpCommand")
    }
}

/// Simple function, using generic to allow the compiler to infer the same types
/// as those inferred in the constant declarations below.
func performWithExecutor<E: Executor, C: Command>(_ executor: E, command: C) {
    executor.execute(command: cmd)
}

// Create command and executor
let cmd = MyCommand()
let httpExecutor = HttpExecutor()

// 1.
// Will output "HttpCommand" (expected)
httpExecutor.execute(command: cmd)

// 2.
// Will output "Not a valid HttpCommand" (unexpected)
performWithExecutor(httpExecutor, command: cmd)

// 3.
let executor: Executor = httpExecutor

// Will output "Not a valid HttpCommand" (expected, not desirable)
executor.execute(command: cmd)
```

In the above, `1` is working as expected. The code flow can correctly infer the types and can correctly dispatch to the generic variant of `execute` in `HttpExecutor`.

`2` is unexpected as use of the generic function should be able to carry the same type information as the inline version.

Finally `3` is somewhat expected, although undesirable.

Any ideas on work arounds here? I gave type erasure a thought but seems like it would yield the same result.

here's the rest of the code...

```swift
import Foundation

// MARK: - Command

/// Basic of all Sonos API commands
public protocol Command {
    associatedtype Request: Encodable
    associatedtype Response: Decodable

    var name: String { get }
    var message: Self.Request? { get }
}

/// A HTTP version of a command
public protocol HttpCommand: Command {
    var httpMethod: String { get }
}

// MARK: - Executor

/// Command executor
protocol Executor {
    func execute<T: Command>(command: T)
}

//
// MARK: -
//

/// Command to return the groups of a Sonos household
public struct MyCommand: HttpCommand {
    public struct Request: Encodable { }
    public struct Response: Decodable {
        public var items: [String]
    }

    public init() { }

    public var name: String = "items"
    public var message: Request?
    public var httpMethod: String { "GET" }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a misuse of generics? Seems to expect generic type constraints to act like overloading, but that's not what they are for and not how they work...? To put it another way, generics have nothing whatever to do with dynamic dispatch; in a way they are the opposite of dynamic dispatch, as there must be nothing dynamic in them — the resolution of a generic must be determined _at compile time_, whereas dynamic dispatch is dynamic _at runtime_.

Comment: @matt, thanks for the feedback. The sample here is cut down, generics were being used in this way because I wanted to avoid the type erasure workaround when using `associatedtype` in the `Command` protocol.

There seems something amiss because 1. works, but the indirection doesn't. Swift I though did support function overloading by type alone. The compiler should seems to be aware of the generic constraints and dispatches correctly when in the flow where the concrete types are inference during assignment.